# Convert a collection of datetime to yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: datetime, powershell

I have a collection of Dates in a text file.

Ex. file.txt

```
2011-01-01

2011-02-14

2011-02-21

2011-03-17

2011-09-11

2011-11-11
```

I have a function called `Important-Dates` which holds a collection of `[datetime]` dates

Ex. Function holds these type of dates

```
November-11-15 12:00:00 AM

November-11-14 12:00:00 AM

November-11-13 12:00:00 AM

February-14-15 12:00:00 AM
```

I want to **convert** the function dates into the format `yyyy-mm-dd` and append to the file.txt file

So far, I have this:

```
$Dates = Important-Dates 
if ( -not (test-path 'file.txt' -pathtype leaf))
{
"{0:yyyy-MM-dd}" -f $Dates | Set-Content 'file.txt'
exit 1
}
else {
"{0:yyyy-MM-dd}" -f @($_.$Dates) | Add-Content 'file.txt'
exit 1
}
```

All I get as a result to the File.txt file is the first date in the Important-Dates list

`"November-11-15 12:00:00 AM"` - which does convert to `2015-11-11`

I want all dates though.  What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing a collection to `-f` will only use the first element in the collection. You want to process each date object in the collection.

To process each object in the collection you can use [foreach-object](http://ss64.com/ps/foreach-object.html):

```
$Dates | ForEach-Object -Process { "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}" -f $_ } | set-content 'file.txt'
}
```

...or more concisely:

```
$Dates | % { "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}" -f $_ } |  Set-Content 'file.txt'
```

Comment: Do you know how I could eliminate identical dates if "2011-11-11" came up twice in the list?

Comment: You shouldn't add questions in the comments. Please create a new question for that problem.

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime` objects can be formatted via their `ToString()` method:

```
$Dates | % { $_.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd') } | Set-Content 'file.txt'
```

Comment: Thank you.  Do you know how I could eliminate an identical date if "2011-11-11" came up twice in the file?